# Failing compilation on Cocoa

Tags: objective-c

ALL,

```
static bool CocoaFileNameGetSensitivity()
{
    NSNumber id;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/"];
    [url getResourceValue: id forKey: NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey error: nil];
    return [id boolValue] == YES;
}
```

I am getting:

```
error: interface type cannot be statically allocated
    NSNumber id;
             ^
             *
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id  _Nullable * _Nonnull' with an lvalue of type 'NSNumber *'
    [url getResourceValue: id forKey: NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey error: nil];
                           ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURL.h:164:55: note: passing argument to
      parameter 'value' here
- (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id _Nullable * _Nonnull)value forKey:(NSURLResourceKey)key error:(out NSError ** _Nullable)error API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.6), ios(4.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                      ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [basedll_cocoa_stdpaths.o] Error 1
Igors-MacBook-Air:buildMac igorkorot$
```

Trying to search with google I see that I need to declare id as a pointer. However doing so I am getting following:

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id  _Nullable * _Nonnull' with an lvalue of type 'NSNumber *'
    [url getResourceValue: id forKey: NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey error: nil];
                           ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURL.h:164:55: note: passing argument to
      parameter 'value' here
- (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id _Nullable * _Nonnull)value forKey:(NSURLResourceKey)key error:(out NSError ** _Nullable)error API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.6), ios(4.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                      ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [basedll_cocoa_stdpaths.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `id` is a pre-existing type in Objective-C so you'll have to use a different name.

Comment: @trojanfoe, what do you mean? Could you please explain? Thx.

Comment: See this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/id).

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to getResourceValue is (ignoring the nonnull stuff) a pointer to an id, or, in other words, a pointer to a pointer to an NSObject. You are passing just a pointer to an NSObject (or, more precisely, a pointer to an NSNumber). Use the '&' operator.